# How to obtain the topology of a Feynman diagram from the list of assigned momenta only?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, momentum, conservation-laws, feynman-diagrams

Let us imagine the following situation. Student A draws a random multi-loop Feynman diagram and assigns momenta to all lines. After that, Student A gives the list of momenta to Student B and asks him/her to reproduce the topology, i.e. the skeleton, of the diagram from the list of momenta only.

I know that it is possible to assign momenta to a given topology algorithmically, but is an algorithm known for the opposite direction, i.e. how to get the topology from a set of momenta?

One-loop example:

Given:

```
independent external momenta (all incoming): p1, p2, p3

loop-momentum: k1

assigned momenta: k1, k1+p1, k1+p1+p2, k1+p1+p2+p3
```

Solution:

```
One-loop box topology
```

Comment: there are integrals involved , so the internal lines cannot have a unique value . see this http://www.ippp.dur.ac.uk/~gudrun/teaching/ILC.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The momentum-space Feynman rules prescribe:

- Internal lines get propagators.
- Vertices come from interactions in the Lagrangian. They get factors
  of the coupling constant times $i$.
- Lines connected to external points do not get propagators.
- Momentum is conserved at each vertex.
- Integrate over undetermined 4-momenta.
- Sum over all possible diagrams.

If the algorithm provides the momenta, but not the vertices, higher order interactions become awkward to sketch.